# Network availble only for social media apps

Tags: android, networking

In my country some mobil network providers offer a mobil network plan that works only with social media network apps (whatapps, twitter....). How can i know when the user is connected to this kind of mobil data service. In android

Comment: maybe try to send a request (and examine the response) to a website that you know that it would be blocked if the user was using such a network

Answer (score 0):

You can get a lot of information from Android's [`ConnectivityManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html). It'll tell you whether you're on WiFi or cellular and whether the network is metered. I'm not sure how it would let you know if it's a special social media network but you might be able to play around with it and get some heuristics.